# Ruby on Rails - Import data from csv file from url

Tags: ruby, csv

I am creating a simple app in Ruby on Rails. Need to import data from cvs files at finance.google.com (an example http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=NYSE:SMH). The program then stores this data for all 500 companies of S&P500 on a daily basis into a database. What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Is your question simply 'how do I open a file given a url' or the full blown 'how do I open a file given a url, and parse its contents, importing said contents in to the database?'

Answer (score 14):

Simplest way could be this, it's almost just like reading a file:

```
require "open-uri"

url = "http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=NYSE:SMH"
url_data = open(url).read()
# favorite way of parsing csv goes here
```

EDIT: that was the approach from a script. For a Rails approach you could write a Rake task to do this, and run it periodically via a scheduled task.

Comment: I like the simple approach, because at the moment, there is no need to a Rails app. A subset with ActiveRecord should be sufficient.

Comment: Hey Tempus, i'm having the same problem now. I tried it but i keep getting "File name to long". Could you take a look ? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23502169/

Answer (score -1):

Please check this gist, pretty sure it will resolve your issue https://gist.github.com/victorhazbun87/9ac786961bbf7c235f76