# Import CSV from url Errno::ENAMETOOLONG: file name too long

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to import a CSV file from a url but i'm getting `Errno::ENAMETOOLONG: file name too long`. I process the file as follow:

```
require 'open-uri'
url = "http://de65.grepolis.com/data/csv.txt"
url_data = open(url).read()

SmarterCSV.process(url_data, {
  ...
})
```

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to pass a filename which should be on server.  rightnow you are passing all data . Do something like this

```
require 'open-uri'
url = "http://de65.grepolis.com/data/csv.txt"
url_data = open(url).read()
File.open('/tmp/file_name', 'w') { |file| file.write(url_data) }
SmarterCSV.process('/tmp/file_name',{ })
```

Comment: Could you join me for a quick chat? -> http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52130/import-csv-from-url-rails

Comment: Correct! SmarterCSV expects a local filename, or a file handle.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem using the standard CSV library to pull in a CSV file via an http url.  I was able to solve the issue without needing to write to a temporary server file with code like this:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'
url = "http://de65.grepolis.com/data/csv.txt"
url_data = open(url).read()
CSV.parse(url_data, headers: true).each do |row|
  # per row processing code ...
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps you.

```
# models/concerns/import.rb

require 'open-uri'
require 'import_error'

module Import
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    def import_remote(url)
      csv = CSV.parse(open(url), headers: true)
      begin
        ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
          counter = 0
          csv.each do |row|
            row_hash = row.to_hash
            begin
              instance = self.name.constantize.create!(row_hash)
            rescue => e
              raise ImportError.new("#{e.message}. at row: #{row_hash}")
            end
            counter += 1 if instance.persisted?
          end
        end
      rescue => e
        return puts e.message
      end
      puts "Imported #{counter} records"
    end
  end
end

# lib/tasks/import.rake

namespace :remote_import do
  desc "Import companies from CSV"
  task :your_model, [:url] do |t, args|
    YourModel.import_remote(args.url)
  end
end

# lib/import_error.rb

class ImportError < StandardError
end

# models/your_model.rb

class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Import
end
```

Gist: https://gist.github.com/victorhazbun87/9ac786961bbf7c235f76

Comment: This solution will meet memory issue with large csv file