# Unable to read googlesheets from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api

I am trying to read a sheet from a multi-sheet google spreadsheet. I am using GoogleAuth API to authorise wuth the service account key. Please see the code snippet below

```
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: credentials1,
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']
  })

const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v2', auth: auth })

const response = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
      spreadsheetId,
      range,
      majorDimension: 'ROWS'
  }
```

Trying to execute this nodejs script and getting this error :

> Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, open".

Comment: This might help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23502169/import-csv-from-url-errnoenametoolong-file-name-too-long